# Is there any function to edit a JSON file in Qt?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have JSON file that contains some text, for example i have "Value": 39 and I want to change the value with for example 12. I know txts are not able to be modified but is there any method from json that does it for me?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Comment: JSON is still text. In-place modifications have all the same caveats and pitfalls. The better approach is still to load->modify->write the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Read the JSON file to `QJsonDocument`, then get the data container where you want to replace the value as `QJsonObject` and then create a new `QJsonValue` with the new value and then replace it in the container by calling https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#insert . And finally write the Json document back to file.